# Complete newbie - tutorial - http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html

Tags: android

First time it worked great.  But after modifying to use resource files I don't get "Hello Android", I get a pretty picture of a phone image with "No service", calm water image, with padlock and speaker image and "charging 50%" etc..

Using Eclipse on Windows Vista.  Tried closing Eclipse, restarting and creating a new project with original "non-resource file" sample but still same pretty picture instead of "Hello Android".

I am a Seasoned Microsoft C#.net developer.  Very impressed by http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html
and Eclipse + SDK, etc was really easy to install and will maybe come over to the "Light Side" if I can get this working!!!!!!!
Cheers.  Ewan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is running in the emulator, you may want to read the screen. It says "Press Menu to unlock."

Pressing the menu key will unlock the screen and the app will be running.

The menu key is a round button in the emulator that says MENU on it in between the one with a house on it and the one with a sideways U-turn.

Comment: Thanks dlongest.  That did the trick!  I can't see anything on the emulator that says "Press Menu to unlock" ..or in the tutorial.  However, I am really really greatful for your speedy help - faster  than IM!  I spent 1 hour downloading the Android/Eclipse stack and over an hour on this problem!